# How to remote invoke another process method from C# application

Tags: c#, methods, process, call

I have a C# app, i want to call a function name for example SendChatMessage(string message, int userid) from my app.But this function belongs another running client/server based application on my computer. I couldn't find the way how i can do this.

I try to make this with Reflection library but failed. Hope someone help me about this.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you control the source code in the other program, or do you want to inject the commands into the process? Then you might have to use DLL-injection to take "control" over the other application.

Comment: Do you own the other app? Is the other app designed to allow other processes to invoke methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using c# to call a function from another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767482/using-c-sharp-to-call-a-function-from-another-process)

Comment: other program 32bit client/server based  directx application. I can't control source code.

Answer (score 17):

Welcome to the world of [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). There are many methods to do this, like named pipes, RPC, shared memory, etc.

In a nutshell, your program is running inside a process. The other program is running inside another process. It's like your father trying to asking something from the boy next-door. These processes can communicate with each other and invoke each other's methods, or use each other's data. But not arbitrarily or course. They need some common standard for communication.

Take a look at these questions:

[What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro)

[What is the best choice for .NET inter-process communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication)

[What is the easiest way to do inter process communication in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802475/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-inter-process-communication-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for answer  but this answer correct if i have control of the other process program code. But i havent control the source code of other program.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the code within the target process, then it sounds like you need to use a means of DLL-injection to inject your code into it.

If the calling process does not need an acknowledgement or response; then injecting code that performs method invocation code may surface, but if a response is required then it is likely that you will need to implement some form of inter-process communication within the code being injected.